# AWS SDK / cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.updateUserPoolClient - Enabled Identity Providers

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Is there any way using the SDK to enable the Cognito User Pool as an identity provider for an app client? We'd like to automate this process with the JS SDK but it doesn't look like an option in the reference docs. We've only been able to do this so far in the AWS console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use the following key

> SupportedIdentityProviders

it takes an array, for example.

```
 await cognito.updateUserPoolClient({
  ClientId: webclientId,
  SupportedIdentityProviders: [
    'COGNITO'
  ],
  AllowedOAuthFlows: ['code'],
  AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true,
  AllowedOAuthScopes: ['email', 'openid', 'profile'],
  CallbackURLs: ['http://localhost:3000/signout'],
  LogoutURLs: ['http://localhost:3000/auth'],
  RefreshTokenValidity: 1
}).promise();
```